# cd directory error when trying to build following Jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, maven, gradle, jenkins, build

Jenkins pipeline script is not running. Can I know  the resaon regarding this Jenkins pipeline script?

```
pipeline {   
    agent any           
    stages{   
        stage('Git checkout'){   
            steps{   
                script{
                  git branch: 'development', credentialsId: '...elided...'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('gradle build'){   
            steps{   
                script{   
                    sh """
                     cd cws/ReportRepo/th.cws/thub/mod.cwscommon
                     ./gradle clean build
                     ./gradle publishToMavenLocal
                    """
                }
            }
        }
        stage('second file gradle build'){   
            steps{   
                script{   
                    sh """
                     cd cws/ReportRepo/th.cws/thub/mod.cwsaudit
                     ./gradle clean build
                     ./gradle publishToMavenLocal
                    """
                }
            }
        }
        stage('third file gradle build'){   
            steps{   
                script{                       
                    sh """
                     cd cws/ReportRepo/th.cws/thub/mod.cwscore
                     ./gradle clean build
                     ./gradle publishToMavenLocal
                    """   
                }
            }
        }
        stage('fourth file gradle build'){   
            steps{   
                script{                       
                    sh """
                     cd cws/ReportRepo/th.cws
                     ./gradle clean build
                     ./gradle publishToMavenLocal
                    """
                }
            }
        }
        stage('file gradle build'){
            steps{
                script{
                    sh """
                     cd cws-batch-api-ms
                     ./gradle clean build
                     cd cws-batch-api-ms/build/l
                     docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t cws-backend .
                   """
                }
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

This error I am getting `cd: directory permission denied`

```
+ cd cws/ReportRepo/th.cws/thub/mod.cwscommon
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/mcn@2@tmp/durable-b82db53a/script.sh: 2: cd: can't cd to cws/ReportRepo/th.cws/thub/mod.cwscommon
```

Comment: Are you sure this `cws/ReportRepo/th.cws/thub/mod.cwscommon` exists in your repository?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running a command in a specific directory, it is better to use the `dir` command in Jenkins instead of using `cd` from the `sh` script:

```
script{
  dir("cws/ReportRepo/th.cws/thub/mod.cwscommon") {
    sh """
       ./gradle clean build
       ./gradle publishToMavenLocal
    """
  }
}
```

Since you are getting a permission denied error, perhaps you Jenkins user doesn't have the necessary permissions to access your `cws` folder? Try manually logging in as the Jenkins user and accessing the folder to see if it is possible. If not, you can give read permissions to the user.